# Get versions of each dll in c# project

Tags: c#, dll, nuget, prism

Currently creating an C# Prism 6 project. It has several modules, some NuGet dependencies and some custom dlls.

The task is to fetch versions of each dll. Is iterating over the folder and fetching versions the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Assembly and FileVersionInfo :

```
 Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
 foreach (var item in assemblies)
 {
     FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(item.Location);
 }
```